# Egress Security Policy with Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm attempting to create an outbound security group policy for `sg1` that has another security group `sg2` as the destination. According to the `authorize_egress()` [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_egress):

**IpPermissions->IPRanges->CidrIp** — You can either specify a CIDR range or a *source security group*, not both. To specify a single IPv4 address, use the /32 prefix length.

**SourceSecurityGroupName** — Not supported. *Use a set of IP permissions to specify a destination security group*.

However, the following code fails with an unexpected parameter type error — does anyone know the syntax for this and/or what I'm doing wrong?

```
sg1 = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName=sg1, Description=sg1, VpcId=vpc.id)

sg1_policy_egress = [{
    'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 
    'FromPort': 443, 
    'ToPort': 443,
    'IpRanges': [{
        'CidrIp': sg2
    }]
}]

sg1.authorize_egress(IpPermissions=sg1_policy_egress)
```

Comment: Could you put the full error message? Also, putting in sample values for your variables like `sg2` and `sg1` would be helpful to see what you're sending, as `sg1` value is reset in your first statement

Comment: Normally, you do not need to worry about egress security group rules. Allow all ports. Use the ingress security group rules to manage systems in a security group. Security Groups are statefull which means they know which egress ports are required for an ingress connection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm building an ethical hacking platform for cybersecurity competitions and need to lock down the network as much as possible at the hypervisor level.

Comment: Make sure to read the AWS Terms of Service. Hacking (Ethical or not) will get your account terminated.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @JohnHanley, already confirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify groups in the `IpRanges` list. You need to use the `UserIdGroupPairs` list instead. I recommend using the `sg2` group ID value for the `GroupId` field. Other ways to specify the destination group are possible, but are not needed for the case you describe.

Specifically you want:

```
sg1_policy_egress = [{
    'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 
    'FromPort': 443, 
    'ToPort': 443,
    'UserIdGroupPairs': [{
        'GroupId': sg2
    }]
}]
```

Comment: This worked, **thank you**! The referenced documentation had me thinking the destination security group was specified as the `CidrIp` value. Appreciate you saving me hours of time and frustration.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept my answer if you are happy with it.